# Javascript browser version lookup array

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I need to check and compare browser versions that are outdated. If the user's browser version is below a defined (<=) version number, a message should appear telling the user to update his/her browser. The version is defined in the following array in my html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

     var browserarr = {Name:"Chrome", ChromeVersion:52, URL:"http://www.google.com",
              Name:"Firefox", FirefoxVersion:40,  URL:"http://www.firefox.com",
              Name:"Safari", SafariVersion:10,  URL:""

              };

</script>
```

My logic has been to code it using if statements but i want another way to do it so that i can fetch the browser family (chrome, firefox or IE) and then the corresponding outdated version and a url to go to update the browser. It should be dynamic so that I only need to add a new line to my array specifying a new browser to make the comparison in javascript.

Check browser

```
detectJS: function () {
    b = detect.parse(navigator.userAgent);

    if (b.browser.family === 'Chrome' && b.browser.major <= browserarr["ChromeVersion"]) {
       document.getElementById('browserNotificationDiv').style.display = "block"; 
        var url = 'google.com';
        //document.getElementById("msgURL").innerHTML = browserarr["URL"];

    }

    if (b.browser.family === 'IE' && b.browser.major <= 9) {
       document.getElementById('browserNotificationDiv').style.display = "block";
       var url = 'ie.com';
    }

    if (b.browser.family === 'Safari' && b.browser.major <= browserarr["SafariVersion"]) {
       document.getElementById('browserNotificationDiv').style.display = "block";
        var url = 'safari.com';
    }

    if (b.browser.family === 'Firefox' && b.browser.major <= browserarr["FirefoxVersion"]) {

       document.getElementById('browserNotificationDiv').style.display = "block";
       var url = 'firefox.com';
    }

    browserDetect.displayInfo(
    'Your current browser ' + b.browser.family + ' version ' + b.browser.major +' is outdated. </br>' +
    'Please download the latest version by going to: ' + url + ' ' + '<a href="'+browserarr["URL"]+'">link</a>' +'</br>'
    );
},
```

How shall I proceed?

Comment: In the code `browserarr` is no an array, it's an Object where `Name` is overwritten.

Comment: Did you check out the existing library that does exactly this? https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser

Comment: Do you have a link for the user to click that says "Thanks, but I'll decide for myself which version of which browser I want to use"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget that does exactly what you are looking for, and you can configure which versions you want to mark as outdated here:

https://updatemybrowser.org/widget.html

But in terms of your current code. I would change your browser object to have a structure more like:

```
var browserList = {
    "chrome" : {
        acceptedVersion: 52,
        downloadUrl: "https://www.google.com"
    },

    "firefox" : {
        acceptedVersion: 40,
        downloadUrl: "https://www.firefox.com"        
    },

    "safari" : {
        acceptedVersion: 10,
        downloadUrl: "https://www.apple.com"        
    }

}
```

Then in your code you can have a switch statement that compares browser name (to lower case to make it easier), then an if statement in that switch clause that checks accepted version and acts on it appropriately.

```
var broswerName = b.browser.family.toLowerCase();

switch(broswerName) {
    case 'chrome':

        if(broswerList[broswerName].acceptedVersion > b.browser.major) {
            //browser is outdated            
        }

        break;
    case 'firefox':

        if(broswerList[broswerName].acceptedVersion > b.browser.major) {
            //browser is outdated            
        }

        break;
}
```